# Decode pair of hex-encoded floats to native float values

Tags: php

I have a device sending its latitude and longitude as a float (lat+lng) to Sigfox:
message starts as -6.60276853.37419

On the device I have to pack the float with micropython due to a 12-byte message length limit:

```
message=struct.pack('f',float(lat)) +struct.pack('f',float(lng))) 
message.send
```

Once it reaches Sigfox, the callback sends it to my server as a hexadecimal message:

```
data=e049d3c02b7f5542
```

And I cant unpack the original float in php:

```
<?php
$_data = $_GET["data"];
$rcvMsgHexString = $_data;  
print("Received message = ".$rcvMsgHexString." [".strlen($$rcvMsgHexString)." characters]\n");

// Convert hex string back to binary string
$rcvMsgString = '';
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
  $byte = substr($rcvMsgHexString,2*$i,2);
  $rcvMsgString[$i] = chr(hexdec($byte));
}
print $rcvMsgString;

// Make sure to unpack in correct order: lat is at start of string
$lat = unpack( "f", $rcvMsgString, 0 );
$lng = unpack( "f", $rcvMsgString, 4 );

if ( $fl = fopen('logs.txt','a')) {
  fwrite($fl,"\"msg\": { \"latitude\" : \"". $lat. "\", "
                       ."\"longitude\" :\"" . $lng . "\" }\n" );
  fclose($fl);
 }
?>
```

lat and lng are just written as blank. Can anyone help me retrieve the original lat and lng properly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to convert the hex digits to actual binary data, then [`unpack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) to extract the float values from the binary:

```
$coords = unpack('flat/flon', pack('H*', $data));
echo $coords['lat'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $coords['lon'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Details:

- `pack('H*', ...)` reads hex digits from `$data`, converting them to binary encoded data.
- `unpack('flat/flon', ...)` reads one float from the binary string, stores it in the resulting array under key `lat`, then reads another float from the binary string and stores it in the resulting array under `lon`.

[See it live on 3v4l.](https://3v4l.org/6c5a6)

Comment: Thank you very much, the two lines of code in your example replace my entire .php function. I was originally trying to print $coord and it only printed "Array" (same as my .php) but the var_dump shows the desired result: array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(53.373859405518) ["lon"]=> float(-6.6025228500366) } .                                                              Can you please clarify how I could extract these with a "print" or echo statetement? I tried "print $coord[2]" since the vardump says array(2) but thats a blank.

Comment: Happy to help, @Jay.F. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: In general, arrays in PHP are zero-indexed, therefore: `echo $coords[0]` and `echo $coords[1]`. The `2` represents the number of elements, which you can also find by `echo count($coords)`. _However_, in this case, the array is keyed by name, so you want `echo $coords['lat']` and `echo $coords['lon']`